# ios build error on codenameone with braintree payments

Tags: ios, codenameone, braintree

Here is a part of logs from cn1 build server

```
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod install Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `BraintreeDropIn` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `BraintreeDropIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] `<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EAD18E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Failed to exec cocoapods.  Trying to update master repo...
Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod repo update Updating spec repo `dwild`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at f0a287f Try even bigger version
Updating spec repo `dwild-1`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at f0a287f Try even bigger version
Updating spec repo `googlemaps`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/googlemaps fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/googlemaps rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/googlemaps reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at 97abfa7 backgroundColors fix (#163)
Updating spec repo `littlemonkeyltd`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/littlemonkeyltd fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/littlemonkeyltd rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/littlemonkeyltd reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at e7db135 update podspec
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
  remote: Counting objects: 495, done.
```

than I setup build hint ios.deployment_target to 8.0 and I got error just little bit different from the previous one:

```
 Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod init Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod install Analyzing dependencies
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "BraintreeDropIn":
   In Podfile:
     BraintreeDropIn

 Specs satisfying the `BraintreeDropIn` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
 Failed to exec cocoapods.  Trying to update master repo...
 Executing: /usr/local/bin/pod repo update Updating spec repo `dwild`
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild fetch origin --progress
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
   master
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild reset --hard origin/master
   HEAD is now at f0a287f Try even bigger version
 Updating spec repo `dwild-1`
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 fetch origin --progress
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
   master
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/dwild-1 reset --hard origin/master
   HEAD is now at f0a287f Try even bigger version
 Updating spec repo `master`
   $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/administrator/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress
   remote: Counting objects: 758           
   remote: Counting objects: 1972, done.
```

so right now i don't really know where the problem could be. It does not look like increasing deployment target could help because I run build for target 10.0 and I got same error.

Comment: FYI I fixed this and if you update the lib/refresh it should work with a big caveat. I used the xcode 9.2 build target which is still highly experimental at this stage. I think it will stabilize quickly but there are still bugs and misbehaviors. I chose to go that way because that's the way we should be going (forward) even though the road is a bit bumpy at this particular point in time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in the current braintree integration due to changes in the cocoapod from braintree. I've had it on my fix list but I've been a bit busy so I'll try to do that over the weekend and post an update here when I'm done.

There are two potential fixes:

- Currently the pod doesn't specify a version which is why this broke. Braintree released an update and everything stopped working. I can just specify a slightly older version and it will start working again.
- We can update to use the new xcode 9.2 support - I think that's the way forward but it's new and I have stability concerns

I'll probably go with the first approach for now.

Comment: @Shai..this issue seems like resurfaced again? I still see the same error in my build as well. Please advise

Comment: I have attached error log this is related to <PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID.

Comment: I need the full log link

Comment: How can i send the full log. Please advise.

Comment: Use the chat on our website to provide us with the link from your build console